# How to extract and translate months from a string variable

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a data.frame of months in both English and Dutch:

```
library(stringr)
months.english <- month.name
months.dutch <- c("januari", "februari", "maart", "april", "mei", "juni","juli", "augustus", "september", "oktober", "november", "december")
months <- data.frame(months.english, months.dutch)
```

I also have a variable of dates, which somewhat unstructured and in both English and Dutch:

```
time <- (c("1 januari 2001", "12 december 2001", "December 9 2001", "2001 maart 13"))
time <- data.frame(time)
time$months <- NA
```

I want to do the following: in the time data.frame I want the months variable to be the month from the dates string, but for those months that are in Dutch, I want the English translation such that dates$months is equal to c("January", "December", "December", "March").

How can I do this the quickest, possibly preventing a for loop (since the actual data.frame has more than 100000 rows)?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a vectorized `stringi` approach.

Step 1: extract the dutch month names:

```
library(stringi)
m <- stri_extract_first(tolower(dates$time), 
          regex = paste(months$months.dutch, collapse = "|"))
```

Step 2: match with english month names:

```
dates$months <- months$months.english[match(m, months$months.dutch)]
```

This should be pretty fast for your data size of 100k rows.

The result is:

```
dates
#              time   months
#1   1 januari 2001  January
#2 12 december 2001 December
#3  December 9 2001 December
#4    2001 maart 13    March
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
months.english <- month.name
months.dutch <- c("januari", "februari", "maart", "april", "mei", "juni","juli", "augustus", "september", "oktober", "november", "december")
months <- data.frame(months.english, months.dutch)

mtable <- data_frame( key = c(months.dutch, months.english),
                      months = rep(months.english, 2))

time <- (c("1 januari 2001", "12 december 2001", "December 9 2001", "2001 maart 13"))
time <- data_frame(time) %>%
  mutate(translate = str_extract(time, "[A-Za-z]+")) %>%
  left_join(mtable, by = c('translate' = 'key'))
```

If you want to use the tidyverse, you can create a key table to join.